# How to automate 'keyboard access' for accessibility testing using protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, accessibility

Can anyone please guide me on how to test web accessibility with protractor tool. 
Or 
How can I automate keyboard access tests using any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but there's a protractor plugin using axe-core https://github.com/angular/protractor-accessibility-plugin

This audits your web site to see if it adheres to the accessibility rules.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Let me go through the link and get back :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, keyboard accessibility can not be automated. Alongside with protractor Axe plugin, you can use [Microsoft Accessibility Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/accessibility-insights-fo/pbjjkligggfmakdaogkfomddhfmpjeni?hl=en) plugin.